# Update query not working using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I tried updating my data like so but it doesn't work

```
<?php
require("config.inc.php");//this piece of code us for authentication and it works fine.


  if(!empty($_POST))
  {
/**
  the values below in the POST are valid not empty values
**/
  $shell = $_POST['shell'];
  $reporter = $_POST['reporter'];

    //query
   $query = "UPDATE `shellingdb`
             SET `likes` = `likes` + 1
              WHERE `shell` = :shell AND `reporter` = :reporter";

           try {
         $query_params =  array(':shell' => $_POST['shell'], ':reporter' => $_POST['reporter']);//Updates likes
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
                    $affected = $stmt->rowCount();//counts the number of affected rows during the update query
        if($affected > 0)
        {
                        $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Updated! this number of rows were affected".$affected;
            echo json_encode($response);
        }else
        {
            $response["success"] = 2;
                $response["message"] = "Not Updated! huh!".$affected;
                echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error!".$ex->getMessage();
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
  }
?>
```

the config.inc.php

```
<?php 

// These variables define the connection information for your MySQL database 
$username = "xmnj3jh0jhtheu_14265914"; 
$password = "jhikjskjiavethew"; 
$host = "sqlkjnlkkjlk101.x3kuhiu0lkj.us"; 
$dbname = "x3lnklj0u_1426jbkb5914_gbabbjkhjajhlert"; 

// UTF-8 is a character encoding scheme that allows you to conveniently store 
// a wide varienty of special characters, like � or �, in your database. 
// By passing the following $options array to the database connection code we 
// are telling the MySQL server that we want to communicate with it using UTF-8 
// See Wikipedia for more information on UTF-8: 
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 
$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 

// A try/catch statement is a common method of error handling in object oriented code. 
// First, PHP executes the code within the try block.  If at any time it encounters an 
// error while executing that code, it stops immediately and jumps down to the 
// catch block.  For more detailed information on exceptions and try/catch blocks: 
// http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php 
try 
{ 
    // This statement opens a connection to your database using the PDO library 
    // PDO is designed to provide a flexible interface between PHP and many 
    // different types of database servers.  For more information on PDO: 
    // http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php 
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    // If an error occurs while opening a connection to your database, it will 
    // be trapped here.  The script will output an error and stop executing. 
    // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
    // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code 
    // (like your database username and password). 
    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 

// This statement configures PDO to throw an exception when it encounters 
// an error.  This allows us to use try/catch blocks to trap database errors. 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

// This statement configures PDO to return database rows from your database using an associative 
// array.  This means the array will have string indexes, where the string value 
// represents the name of the column in your database. 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

// This block of code is used to undo magic quotes.  Magic quotes are a terrible 
// feature that was removed from PHP as of PHP 5.4.  However, older installations 
// of PHP may still have magic quotes enabled and this code is necessary to 
// prevent them from causing problems.  For more information on magic quotes: 
// http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php 
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
{ 
    function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array) 
    { 
        foreach($array as &$value) 
        { 
            if(is_array($value)) 
            { 
                undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $value = stripslashes($value); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST); 
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET); 
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE); 
} 

// This tells the web browser that your content is encoded using UTF-8 
// and that it should submit content back to you using UTF-8 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 

// This initializes a session.  Sessions are used to store information about 
// a visitor from one web page visit to the next.  Unlike a cookie, the information is 
// stored on the server-side and cannot be modified by the visitor.  However, 
// note that in most cases sessions do still use cookies and require the visitor 
// to have cookies enabled.  For more information about sessions: 
// http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php 
session_start(); 

// Note that it is a good practice to NOT end your PHP files with a closing PHP tag. 
// This prevents trailing newlines on the file from being included in your output, 
// which can cause problems with redirecting users.

?>
```

don't know what's wrong and it gives no error it goes into the else statement, meaning the values were not updated. i tried the same code in sqlfiddle and it works but not in my PhpMyAdmin.

I know the updated value is supposed to be passed into the $query_params but am incrementing the value of likes each time it is run, and am not sure how to do that in the $query_params unless i use a seperate query to get the numberof likes and then increament it but that could be costly.

Query without PDO still it does not work this time it give update unsuccessful

```
<?php

$username = "x3jbhiukhkj0u426jbhjnbvh591mbhb4"; 
$password = "savjiuejbiuhilkmthljiew"; 
$host = "sqlnjhbjhnkjjjhbj"; 
$dbname = "x3hjbh0ukjioiuhgbjhvhgvh";

 $shell = "Rustig";
 $reporter = "davies";

  //query
  $query = "UPDATE `shellingdb`
            SET `favs` = 1
            WHERE `shell` = 'Rustig'";


$link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
if (!$link) 
{
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}else
{
     echo 'Connected successfully';
     $db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbname, $link);

         if (!$db_selected) 
         {
               die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
         }else
         {
              echo 'Connected to database successfully';

              if(empty($_POST))
              {
                $retval = mysql_query( $query, $link )or die(mysql_error($link));;
                if(! $retval )
                {
                     die('Could not query database: ' . mysql_error());
                }else
                {
                      if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
                      {
                           echo "Updated data successfully\n";
                      }else
                      {
                           //echo "shell=".$shell." reporter=".$reporter';
                           echo "Updated data Unsuccessfully\n";
                      }
                }
             }
         }
}
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

The below is the output of the    PDOStatement::debugDumpParams(); for the first php syntax

> SQL: [124] UPDATE `shellingdb` SET `likes` = `likes` + 1 WHERE `shell` = :shell AND `reporter` >= :reporter Params: 2 Key: Name: [6] :shell paramno=-1 name=[6] ":shell" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [9] :reporter paramno=-1 name=[9] ":reporter" is_param=1 param_type=2

Comment: Do you need the colons in the keys of your $query_params array?  I thought you just needed the variable you're replacing (sans colon).

Comment: Try outputting your query to see if it's what you expect it to be.  C.f. `PDOStatement::debugDumpParams` http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php

Comment: @AlexDavies You will not need to increase by `$query_params`. Your SQL is correct. Appeared any mistake? Replace `!empty` for `isset`. You have the line `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` to show the exception?

Comment: @LucasHenrique so do i need to replace $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); with $result = $stmt->execute();

Comment: @LucasHenrique no i haven't solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some how, after long hours of try and error(Brut Forcing) this finally worked

```
$query = "UPDATE `shellingdb` SET `likes`=`likes`+1 WHERE `shell` = :shell AND `reporter`     = :reporter";
```

Thanks all those who tried to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I used bindParam. [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) is a method on PDOStatement.

Try:

```
<?php
require("config.inc.php");//this piece of code us for authentication and it works fine.


if(isset($_POST))
{
    /**
     the values below in the POST are valid not empty values
     **/
    $shell = $_POST['shell'];
    $reporter = $_POST['reporter'];

    //query
    $query = "UPDATE `shellingdb`
    SET `likes` = `likes` + 1
    WHERE `shell` = :shell AND `reporter` = :reporter";

    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(":shell", $shell);
        $stmt->bindParam(":reporter", $reporter);
        $stmt->execute();

        $affected = $stmt->rowCount();//counts the number of affected rows during the update query
        if($affected > 0)
        {
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Updated! this number of rows were affected".$affected;
            echo json_encode($response);
        }else
        {
            $response["success"] = 2;
            $response["message"] = "Not Updated! huh!".$affected;
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error!".$ex->getMessage();
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Still it doesn't work. it confussing and it shows no errors! ):

Comment: @AlexDavies Your connection is correct? Is selecting the seat correctly?

Comment: the connection is correct cause it the same thing i use from my other codes and it connects  besides it would report an error if it didn't connect, and the column names are also correct. or is it my database version or configuration?

Comment: @AlexDavies Put var_dump in `$shell` and `$reporter` and check if is correct.

Comment: did it and the values are correct.Right now am fustrated. )':

Comment: @AlexDavies The `$db` object is connection in `config.inc.php`?

Comment: i will post the config.inc.php

Comment: @AlexDavies The return is always `Not Updated! huh!`?

Comment: @AlexDavies Solved the problem?

Comment: @AlexDavies The only thing missing is the HTML form post.

Comment: it android and it fine cause I tested to receive values and it works, I get my values